# Flutter How to position a Card with ClipPath in Stack?

Tags: flutter

I actually tried multiple solutions but i don't know why it can't be positioned!?
Here is the code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:smart_tank1/widgets/home_widget.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';


class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                children: [
                  ClipPath(
                    clipper: DrawClip(),
                    child: Container(
                      height: size.height,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              colors: [Color(0xff46ddbf), Color(0xff3088e2)],
                              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                              end: Alignment.bottomLeft
                              )
                              ),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                    height: size.height,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 40,),
                        Container(
                          height: 80,
                          width: 80,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: Icon(Icons.person, size: 40, color: Colors.grey,),
                            ),
                        ),
                      SizedBox(height: 40,),
                       Row(
                         children: [                     
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                                child: Text('Today', 
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ), 
                         ],
                       ), 
                       SizedBox(height: 10,),
                       Row(
                         children: [                     
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  DateFormat('dd-MM-yyy').format(DateTime.now()).toString(), 
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ), 
                         ],
                       ),
                      
                        
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
               ],
                ),
                  ),
                  ),                   
                        SizedBox(
                             height: 200,
                             width: double.infinity,
                             child: Padding(
                               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                child: Card(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    ),
                                  elevation: 5,
                                  child: Text('Here'),
                                ),
                             ),
                           ),
                      
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class DrawClip extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    // TODO: implement getClip
    Path path = Path();
    path.addOval(
        Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(size.width * 0.5, 50.0), radius: 300));
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have tried a lot of things like Positioned widget and SizedBox even i tried to seperate widgets and do the work out of the Column widget but i couldn't reach any result to make it work  it didn't work and i don't why? everything seems to work fine but it doesn't, please help!

You can find what i'm trying to reach described in the picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA0Zp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Refer `Positioned` Class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)

Refer `Stack` Class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```
     Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              ClipPath(
                clipper: DrawClip(),
                child: Container(
                  height: size.height,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [Color(0xff46ddbf), Color(0xff3088e2)],
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomLeft)),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: size.height,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 80,
                              width: 80,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.person,
                                  size: 40,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 40,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Today',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                                  child: Text('ok'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ), 
              Positioned(
                top: 200,
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      elevation: 5,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Here',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Your Result screen-> [image]

Comment: @Abddi Welcome, if your problem has been solved Accept my answer Thanks,